# Change recorded video orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avassetwriter

I have a video in app documents dir that is in landscape mode. I want to change its orientation to portrait mode permanently. Does any know how can I do that using code? Is there any tutorial or sample? After hours of googling I couldn't find anything on this topic.

NOTE: I want to change the orientation completely not just change it at MPMoviePlayerController. So if the user were to share that movie on Facebook, twitter etc it will always be shown there in portrait mode

```
-(IBAction)changeMovieToPortrait
{
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES);
    NSString* documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* movieFile1 = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"movie1.mov"];

    NSURL *movURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:movieFile1];

    NSMutableDictionary* myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] ,
                                   AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey ,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                   AVURLAssetReferenceRestrictionsKey, nil];

    AVURLAsset* movie = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:movURL options:myDict];

    //not sure how to do it here
}
```

Comment: If my answer helps you then please make my answer right or may be if you found other way to do this then please post your solution here it will helps to others

Comment: @AnandK did you delete your answer? As it seems to be cached here http://www.ggkf.com/iphone/change-recorded-video-orientation

Comment: Ya and some one copy my answer and post on her site